# Falling into an infinite loop when trying to implement Infinite Scrolling using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

Assistance would be much appreciated with the following issue.

My code falls into an infinite loop when scrolling-up a tableView even though I have implemented the right boolean checks (so I believe)...

`Bool` to check if I am already fetching more content:

```
var fetchingMore = false
```

This is my `scrollViewDidScroll` func:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.height{

        if !fetchingMore{

            radius += 5
            fetchMoreVenues()

        }//end if

    }//end if

}//end func
```

This is my `fetchMoreVenues` func which fetches more content **but is being called infinitely for some reason**:

```
func fetchMoreVenues(){

    fetchingMore = true

    DataService.run.fetchVenueNearby(deviceLocation: currentLocation, radius: radius) { (venues) in

        for venue in venues {

            if !self.venueArray.contains(where: { ($0.venueID == venue.venueID) }){
                self.venueArray.append(venue)
            }

            if !self.filteredVenueArray.contains(where: { ($0.venueID == venue.venueID) }){
                self.filteredVenueArray.append(venue)
            }

        }//end for

        self.fetchingMore = false
        self.tableView.reloadData() 

    }//end fetchVenueNearby

}//end func
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be reverse order

```
self.tableView.reloadData() 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
  self.fetchingMore = false
}
```